# Qt QFileDialog::setDirectory funny behavior in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qfiledialog

I have a class that inherits from `QFileDialog`. In the constructor, I call `setDirectory` and pass in the last directory visited (which the class keeps track of; see code below). On Windows, this works fine. And if I show the dialog multiple times, it is internally smart enough to resume at the last location (e.g. where the user saved a file before). This is the desired behavior.

On Ubuntu 12.04 (GCC 4.8 compiler), on the other hand, the system does not automatically resume where last left off if I call `showFileDialog` multiple times. So I tried adding the `setDirectory` call within that function as commented below, but that didn't change anything. Furthermore, if I take out `setDirectory` from the constructor so it is only called in `showFileDialog`, the file dialog opens to the folder from which the program was run. (i.e. setDirectory didn't work.) Subsequent calls to `showFileDialog` will open a file dialog starting in the directory requested.

So it seems like the call has a delayed effectiveness. Is this a Qt bug, or mine? Either way, how can I get the `setDirectory` call to be effective?

**Example code:**

```
QString FileDialog::defaultDir = QDir::homePath();

FileDialog::FileDialog(QWidget *parentWindow /*, ...*/)
    : QFileDialog(parentWindow)
{
    setDirectory(defaultDir);
    //...
}

QString FileDialog::showFileDialog()
{
    // Adding setDirectory(defaultDir) here doesn't help.

    if(!exec())
    {
        return QString::null;
    }

    defaultDir = directory().path();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Native dialogs may have limitations. Try to use `DontUseNativeDialog` option.

Comment: I forgot to mention: I did verify that DontUseNativeDialog makes it work fine, but I would prefer to keep the Ubuntu feel with a native dialog.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the code above how you know that the path was changed. I'm not sure that `directory()` is responsible for that.

Consider using `void QFileDialog::directoryEntered(const QString & directory)` signal.

Comment: I know the path by looking at the file dialog UI, but now I tried checking that signal as well. The `directoryEntered` signal reports the current directory at the moment the dialog is opened and then every time I move to a different folder within the dialog. It does not appear to be triggered by a call to `setDirectory`.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround found:

I happen to set the dialog title (`setWindowTitle()`) every time I open a `FileDialog`. If I connect to the `QFileDialog::windowTitleChanged` signal and call `setDirectory` within the slot, it is effective.

This is an unintuitive workaround though, so I am open to better answers.